# Runtime Error Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using **import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'** storage

give Runtime error **Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined** when use **this.storage.remove('key');**
[image: Error]

**this is my function code where i used:this.storage.remove**

```
logout(): void {
            this.storage.remove(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN);
            this.storage.remove('email');
            this.events.publish('user:logout');
          };
```

Comment: Where is storage defined?

Comment: did you add the @ionic/storage to app.module.ts ?

Comment: yes storage.set() and storage.get() working fine

Comment: Is logout() function a callback function?

Comment: no its not call back function

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject a `storage` object in the constructor:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

constructor(private storage: Storage) {

}

logout(): void {
    this.storage.remove(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN);
    this.storage.remove('email');
    this.events.publish('user:logout');
};
```

Note that you also have to register the storage module in your app:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // ...
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        // ...
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See [this documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

Comment: yes @devqon i imported IonicStorageModule  in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

install ionic-native package > $ npm install ionic-native --save

and use it like:

```
import { Storage } from 'ionic-native

//and in component class call it like this

Storage.remove('email');
```

you dont need to inject it if you are not using wrapper